# Time-sensitive Cloudant view not always returning correct results

Tags: view, cloudant

I have a view on a Cloudant database that is designed to show events that are happening in the next 24 hours:

```
function (doc) {

  // activefrom and activeto are in UTC 
  // set start to local time in UTC
  var m = new Date();
  var start = m.getTime();

  // end is start plus 24 hours of milliseconds
  var end = start + (24*60*60*1000);

  // only want approved disruptions for today that are not changed conditions
  if (doc.properties.status === 'Approved' && doc.properties.category != 'changed' && doc.properties.activefrom && doc.properties.activeto){
     if (doc.properties.activeto > start && doc.properties.activefrom < end)
       emit([doc.properties.category,doc.properties.location], doc.properties.timing);    
     }
  }
}
```

This works fine for most of the time but every now and then the view does not show the expected results.

If I edit the view, even just adding a comment, the output changes to the expected results. If I re-edit the view and remove the change, the results return to the incorrect results.

Is this because of the time-sensitive nature of the view? Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date that is indexed by your MapReduce function is the time that the server dealing with the work performs the indexing operation.

Cloudant views are not necessarily generated at the point that data is added to the database. Sometimes, depending on the amount of work the cluster is having to do, the Cloudant indexer is not triggered until later. Documents can even remain unindexed until the view is *queried*. In that circumstance, the date in your index would not be "the time the document was inserted" but "the time the document was indexed/queried", which is probably not your intention.

Not only that, different shards (copies) of the database may process the view build at different times, giving you inconsistent results depending on which server you asked!

You can solve the problem by indexing something from your source document e.g.

if your document looked like:

`{
  "timestamp": 1519980078159,
  "properties": {
    "category": "books",
    "location": "Rome, IT"
  }
}`

You could generate an index using the `timestamp` value from your document and the view you create would be consistent across all shards and would be deterministic.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I converted the properties that I'm comparing to UTC. I'm assuming that if I convert 'now' to UTC then I'm comparing everything in the same timezone ie UTC. My events have a start and end date, so I'm not using the one property. I thought that if everything is using UTC then I wouldn't have a timezone issue (I'm actually in Australia).

Comment: It's really the time when the view is queried that I'm interested in using for the comparison.

Comment: The view creation time, as I say, is a movable feast. It'll vary depending on load, whether you query the view and on a per-shard basis.

Comment: Thanks @Glynn Bird. I had a really over-simplistic idea that the view was run close to each time it was called! I have to check that now is between a start and end date. I played with setting up a view that created an index entry for every day that an event was active for. That works fine and means I can use start_key and end_key on the URL for querying. But I really wanted to be able to have a static URL that could return 'todays' events. I guess that's not going to be possible.